# how to set background color like in picture

Tags: html, css, web

Please check the image i want to set the background like that what i  use is that

```html
<p style="background: #FEEC00; background-height: 15px; backgound-width: 219px; position: absolute; font-family: DIN Pro; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; line-height: 23px; color: #333333;" ></p>
```

but it is not setup like the picture
[image]

Comment: Please add more explanation and your code and describe exactly what you want to see.

Comment: This question may be irrelevant but how did he get the commentor badge? Look at his rep!

Comment: @AHaworth please read the question again

Comment: @JackJohnson i don't understand why this question is irrelevant

Comment: Your question is badly written, you need help? do an effort so we easily get what you have and what you try to do. ;) Added a snippet to your question, please add your relevant HTML/CSS to demonstrate your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    padding:30px 30px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    outline-color: none;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: #DDD;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    max-width:500px;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
.wrapper p
{
  font-size:4em;
  margin:auto;
  z-index:1;
  display:flex;
}
.imgbackground{
   position:absolute;
   background:#FEEC00;
   height:50px;
   flex-grow:1;
   margin:auto;
   width:92%;
   top:66px;
}
.imgbackground .child{
   background:#EE5566;
   height:3px;
   width:100%;
   margin-top:21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>LICHTOMTWERP</p>
    <div class="imgbackground">
       <div class="child">
        
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with background gradients

```
background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #FEEC00 50%, #FEEC00 100%)
```

Or another solution will be to use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` and create this yellow box which you can set to `position:absolute` inside a parent with `position:relative`